# Facebook Credits - getOrders call for refunds/chargebacks

Tags: facebook-graph-api, payment, facebook-credits, credits

I am using the Get Orders call for our app as specified in:
developers.facebook.com/docs/creditsapi/

It all works fine when I set the `status=settled`, but if I set the status to reserved or refunded, then I get no results.  This is even over a period where I know we had refunds/chargebacks.

This works:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID/payments?status=settled&since=1320537600&until=1320624000&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

But this never returns anything:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID/payments?status=refunded&since=1320537600&until=1320624000&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Has anyone else had any luck with this API call?  Are my expectations wrong? (I am expecting to get a result if a refund occurred within the specified time frame).

---

If anyone else is experiencing this, a bug has been opened and assigned with high priority here: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/159012307531417